# List of killed processes HP-UX

Tags: process, hp-ux

Is there a file similar to the one in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10078/5027 to determine the processes which were killed, in a certain time, for example, yesterday, in HP-UX?

Answer (score 0):

Check the system log - there should be an indication when processes are killed.

For `HP-UX` this is normally /var/adm/syslog/syslog`.

Comment: I checked it already, there is no indication :(