# OOM Killer - save cmdline & owner about process being killed

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

I'm aware OOM killer save info about a pid in syslog, but I would like to collect also cmdline & owner of process being killed.

Info is relevant for debugging and ELK metrics, just PID isn't helpful. 
I couldn't find a tool or an easy way to do so,

any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/oom_dump_tasks
```

which seems is the most that you can get the kernel to display on out-of-memory errors.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

> Enables a system-wide task dump (excluding kernel threads) to be
>   produced when the kernel performs an OOM-killing and includes such
>   information as pid, uid, tgid, vm size, rss, nr_ptes, swapents,
>   oom_score_adj score, and name.  This is helpful to determine why the
>   OOM killer was invoked, to identify the rogue task that caused it, and
>   to determine why the OOM killer chose the task it did to kill.
>
> If this is set to zero, this information is suppressed.  On very large
>   systems with thousands of tasks it may not be feasible to dump the
>   memory state information for each one.  Such systems should not be
>   forced to incur a performance penalty in OOM conditions when the
>   information may not be desired.
>
> If this is set to non-zero, this information is shown whenever the OOM
>   killer actually kills a memory-hogging task.

## Edit

As per [Where can I see a list of kernel killed processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-kernel-killed-processes)

Process Accounting could help here.

In brief:

```
apt-get install acct
```

Then try commands like:

```
lastcomm
sa
```

or on Ubuntu:

```
lastcomm -f /var/log/account/pacct
sa /var/log/account/pacct
```

See:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/pasetup.html
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/misccommands.html